# SSH into remote computer and compile/run code

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I made a script (below) that goes into a remote computer and runs C code on it. This script works perfectly but asks for the password multiple times. How can I make it only ask for the password once?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

USER=myusername
COMP=remote_computer_name
OUTPUT=$1
ARGS=${@:2}
CODE_DIR="Dir_$$"
SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $0)
LAST_CREATED_DIR=$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1)

#Check if we are on local computer. If so, we copy the 
#current directory to the remote run this script on the remote 
if [ "${HOSTNAME}" != "${COMP}" ]; then
  if [ "$#" -lt  1 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect usage."
    echo "Usage: ./${SCRIPT_NAME} <compiled_c_output_name> <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>"
    exit
  fi
  # Check if there is no makefile in the current directory
  if [ ! -e [Mm]akefile ]; then
    echo "There is no makefile in this directory"
    exit
  fi
  echo "On local. Copying current directory to remote..."
  scp -r ./ ${USER}@${COMP}:/ilab/users/${USER}/${CODE_DIR}
  ssh ${USER}@${COMP} "bash -s" < ./${SCRIPT_NAME} ${OUTPUT} ${ARGS}

else
  echo "On remote. Compiling code..."
  cd $LAST_CREATED_DIR
  make clean
  make all
  if [ -e $OUTPUT ]; then
    echo "EXECUTING \"./${OUTPUT} ${ARGS}\" ON REMOTE ($COMP)"
    ./${OUTPUT} ${ARGS}
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Public key authentication?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Can you show me an example? I have tried public key auth but it still asks for password

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH-Key authentication technique for password less login -

Here are the steps :

- Generate RSA key -

  `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

  This generates two files under `/home/<user>/.ssh/`  `id_rsa`
  (Private) and `id_rsa.pub` (Public)
- The second file is your public key. You have to copy the contents of
  this file over to the remote computer you want to log into and append
  it to `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` or use `ssh-copy-id`
  utility if available (`ssh-copy-id username@remote_host`)

  After this, the authentication is done by the public-private key pair
  and you may not require a password henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sshpass. Here is an example:

```
sshpass -pfoobar ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command_to_run
```

More info, here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass

Comment: Any way I can avoid dependencies? I'm trying to make this script for me and my classmates

Comment: The only other way that I know could be a ssh key to avoid using a password. Check this: [Automate ssh login](http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)

Comment: I saw that answer. Still couldn't do it. Thats why I posted my question. I think its different if you are trying to create private keys in a script